# Double Click Functionality in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to crystal reporting. I have created some simple reports quite successfully but now I am stuck at one report. The requirement is to provide double click functionality on some table column fields. I have searched this scenario over the internet and found that this thing can be achieved by implementing On-Demand Report but no one have explained how to achieve this... Can anybody provide with some examples/tutorial on this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you would like to happen once a user clicks on a field?

Comment: On click, I want to open new report.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I know double click functionality is not possbile in crystal report and coming to **ondemand subreport**. it provides click functionality but its a sub report so by using more and more ondemand subreport your report performance will be effected